# What are the names of each section of IPv4 address?

Tags: networking, ip

I am writing a UI class for handling IP address and I was wondering if a specific name exists for each of the four sections of IP address V4, to distinguish each part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a mistake to think of an IP address as four octets. Ever since [Classless Interdomain Routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) came in over 20 years ago they are called 'bits'. There are now only two parts: the 'network address', which is the part that is masked in by the netmask, and the 'host identifier', which is the part that is masked out. The two parts are of variable length depending on the netmask.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is not.
You could just name them first, second, etc...

Comment: Thanks. It is kinda odd that there is no name to differentiate each!

Comment: First, second, third and fourth *octets*